# Does a 'low backlight dimmed constantly turned on screen' use battery & can it burn in?

Tags: display, battery, screen, widgets

TL;DR: Can a smartphone LCD screen burn in when emitting nearly no light, but just dark dimmed pixels? And could, by such way, a screen-on time of 8 hours be achieved?

---

I'm designing a concept that requires quick access (from lock screen to tap in app in 1 second) to a single function inside an app. Since the lock screen for users without TouchID takes quite some time, relatively, I thought to force the display to remain turned on. The app should be used during conference presentations and since some conferences are a full day of length most smartphones can't survive that long with the screen turned on.

To save the battery I thought of over-dimming the backlight/screen of the device and become lighter when used. It's an extension of the default dim functionality. But I was worried that

1. The screen might burn in when having the screen turned on for an hour using black pixels on LCD displays and non-transitioning graphics (like a screensaver).
2. Even by dimming the brightness to an extreme level, that might not extend the battery life to an 8-hour of constant-on screen time.

Since you don't need to see the screen actually, and actions are confirmed  by vibrating, the screen could be dimmed extremely. Therefor I'm looking to confirm my thoughts.

---

*Too bad you can't run an app in the background and execute actions from the lockscreen, multiple times, without unlocking the device. Neither widgets can, as far as I know.. That would solve the whole issue of being quickly accessible, turned on screens and saving battery life..*.

*<sup>I wrote this, because I might be wrong and you might know an alternative.</sup>*

Comment: Widgets can do things from the lock screen as you mentioned, but they might be suitable — it depends what exactly you want to do. A button in a widget can do a variety of things. You're welcome to provide further details of your intention in [chat]?

Comment: I've posted an extended message in the chat. I'm unsure whether I did it correctly, since it looks a bit plain. I've mentioned your name (@grgarside) but it isn't clickable. So Perhaps I did something wrong? :) I hope the explanation of the functionality is clear.